# Proving things for an infinite union of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was recently asked to prove something about $\bigcup^\infty_{i=1}A_i$. I recall learning that it's not sufficient to prove the necessary statement instead about $\bigcup^n_{i=1}A_i$ for all $n$ (if it is true). Why is this so? Are there any illuminating counterexamples? It seems that proving the latter implies the former.

Comment: Suppose that each of the $A_i$ is finite and the assertion is that the union is finite?

Comment: @EthanBolker Don't you mean that the assertion is that the union is finite?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Yes. Since you caught this in under five minutes I could fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you wanted to prove that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \{1,\ldots,i\}$ is a finite set.

Clearly you can't do it by proving that for every value of $n$, $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{1,\ldots,n\}$ is a finite set.  Proving the latter is easy; proving the former is impossible.

Next, suppose you want to prove that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty [i,i+5]$ is bounded.  That's impossible, but it's easy to show $\bigcup_{i=1}^n [i,i+5]$ is bounded for every $n$.

Suppose you want to prove that the set of inequalities $\{\text{“} i < x\in\mathbb N\text{''}: i = 1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is consistent, i.e. it can be solved for $x\in\mathbb N$.  That's impossible, but it's not hard to show that $\{\text{“}i < x\in\mathbb N\text{''}: i = 1,\ldots,n\}$ is consistent for every $n$.

Answer (score 2):

The finite union of closed sets is closed, but the infinite union may not be.  Let $A_i=[\frac 1i,1]$  Any finite union is the same as the highest index set in the union and therefore closed.  The infinite union is $(0,1]$, which is not.